# Querying table by subtable that matches some properties in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (simplified as):

```
Documents [DOC_Id, DOC_Guid]

DocumentProperties [DOP_Id, DOC_Id, DOC_Key, DOC_Value]
```

`DocumentProperties` has the dynamic properties of the document and I want to query by some of them to find a document, so I call that query:

```
SELECT DOC_Guid
FROM Documents 
WHERE DOC_Id IN (SELECT DP.DOC_Id FROM DocumentProperties DP 
                 WHERE DOC_Key = 'Prop1' AND DOC_Value = 'Val1') 
  AND DOC_Id IN (SELECT DP.DOC_Id FROM DocumentProperties DP 
                 WHERE DOC_Key = 'Prop2' AND DOC_Value = 'Val2') 
  .....
  AND DOC_Id IN (SELECT DP.DOC_Id FROM DocumentProperties DP 
                 WHERE DOC_Key = 'PropN' AND DOC_Value = 'ValN')
```

But in some cases (in very big databases), I get a very strange error message:

> SQL Server error query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan.

I've created the suggested indexes from query tuning advisor, but it isn't enough.

Is there any other way to optimize that query or change it completely perhaps to avoid that error?

Comment: The trouble you have is well documented in Stephane faroult video on Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40Lnoyv-sXg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use subqueries when JOIN is possible ?

```
SELECT DOC_Guid
FROM   Documents AS D
       JOIN DocumentProperties AS DP1 ON D.DOC_ID = DP1.DOC_Id
       JOIN DocumentProperties AS DP2 ON D.DOC_ID = DP2.DOC_Id
       ...
WHERE  DP1.DOC_Key = 'Prop1' AND DP1.DOC_Value = 'Val1'
  AND  DP2.DOC_Key = 'Prop2' AND DP2.DOC_Value = 'Val2'
  ...
```

This will reduce the extraordinary cost of the query...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT d.DOC_Guid
FROM Documents d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DocumentProperties DP WHERE DP.DOC_Id = D.DOC_ID AND DOC_Key = 'Prop1' AND DOC_Value = 'Val1') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DocumentProperties DP WHERE DP.DOC_Id = D.DOC_ID AND DOC_Key = 'Prop2' AND DOC_Value = 'Val2') AND
      . . .;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `DocumentProperties(DOC_Id, DOC_KEY, DOC_VALUE)`.  That should eliminate resource issues.